# what is the format of sklearn cluster labels?

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm using sklearn to cluster some lines of text, but trying to understand the format of the returned cluster labels. It looks like this:

```
km_model.labels_
array([ 5, 35,  1, 29, 49,  2,  6, 28,  5,  4,  4, 19, 40, 52,  6, 20,  4,\n       40, 40,  7, 10, 13, 14,  4, 10, 29, 14, 22, 24, 13, 24,  5,  4, 21,\n ...
```

So it's kind of like an array but there are elements of `\n` to separate clusters?
Is that really the format?
Is this some type of shortcut method for packing matrices in SKLearn? Why don't they return a 2D array of labels, eg one list of labels per cluster?

After that what is the best way to iterate through this type of data and group the labels per cluster?

Comment: How do you mean that? For every input you get a label back, so if you have 10 input points (with several features) you will get 10 labels back

Answer (score 0):

Your clusters are the number values, the index of each label corresponds to the index of the samples you passed into your model. I suspect the `\n` is resulting from whatever IDE you're using read this output.